# How to get a shared observable to emit a new value from .startWith() every time a shared stream gets a new subscriber?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I need a shared observable to emit a new `.startWith()` value every time a shared stream is subscribed to (subscriber count goes from 0 to 1). Unfortunately the value returned by `.startWith()` is being reused across the lifetime of the shared observable instance, even after this shared stream has no subscribers.

Ideally there would be a `.startWith()` overload that takes a function as a parameter and re-executes it every time the subscriber count changes from 0-1.

```
var count: Int = 0

@Before
fun setUp() {
    count = 0 //reset
}

fun getTheCount(): Int {
    count++
    return count
}

@Test
fun startWithDefaultValue() {
    val relay = PublishRelay.create<Int>()

    val instance by lazy {
        relay
                .startWith(getTheCount())
                .share()
    }

    val disposable1 = instance.subscribe {
        println(it) //should print 1, and does!
    }

    disposable1.dispose() //subscriber count on shared instance drops from 1 to 0

    //should print 2, but prints 1. getTheCount() is not called again on this subscription
    val disposable2 = instance.subscribe {
        println(it) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `val instance by lazy` means initialize once and thus you have a single call to `getTheCount()` method. (I also hope you understand that `Observable.just(getTheCount())` will emit the same value to every observer and never "call" `getTheCount()` again.)

You should either defer the lazy internals:

```
Observable.defer(() -> relay.startWith(getTheCount()))
.share();
```

Or use `fromCallable` and concatWith:

```
relay.concatWith(Observable.fromCallable(() -> getTheCount()))
.share();
```

Comment: note, I went with `.startWith(Observable.fromCallable{ getTheCount })`